# Preemptive authentication - HttpComponentsMessageSender

Tags: spring-integration

How to enable preemptive authentication in HttpComponentsMessageSender

```
<bean id="httpComponentsMessageSender" class="org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpComponentsMessageSender">
    <property name="credentials">
        <bean class="org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials">
            <constructor-arg value="userName"/>
            <constructor-arg value="password"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Error:

```
<faultcode>soapenv:Server.Transport.Http.401</faultcode><faultstring>1136 The HTTP Webservice returned an error: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized</faultstring>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to inject a customized `HttpClient` into sender instead. And that customized client you can implement according official Apache Doc: https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/authentication.html

> HttpClient does not support preemptive authentication out of the box, because if misused or used incorrectly the preemptive authentication can lead to significant security issues, such as sending user credentials in clear text to an unauthorized third party.

**UPDATE**

The `HttpComponentsMessageSender` has this method:

```
/**
 * Template method that allows for creation of a {@link HttpContext} for the given uri. Default implementation
 * returns {@code null}.
 *
 * @param uri the URI to create the context for
 * @return the context, or {@code null}
 */
protected HttpContext createContext(URI uri) {
    return null;
}
```

So, looks like for Preemptive authentication we need to extend `HttpComponentsMessageSender` and implement that method to provide a required `context` like it is shown in that Apache Commons doc:

```
protected HttpContext createContext(URI uri) {
    HttpHost targetHost = new HttpHost("localhost", 80, "http");
    CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    credsProvider.setCredentials(
         new AuthScope(targetHost.getHostName(), targetHost.getPort()),
         new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username", "password"));

    AuthCache authCache = new BasicAuthCache();
    BasicScheme basicAuth = new BasicScheme();
    authCache.put(targetHost, basicAuth);


    HttpClientContext context = HttpClientContext.create();
    context.setCredentialsProvider(credsProvider);
    context.setAuthCache(authCache);
    return context;
}
```

Of course, this `context` has to be cached on the instance level for future reuse in each `httpclient.execute()`.

Comment: Thanks. If the server port and credentials, are specified as part of custom httpclient,  do I need to create HttpComponentsMessageSender again with credentials? If I am creating bean - HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
response = client.execute(
  new HttpGet(URL_SECURED_BY_BASIC_AUTHENTICATION), context);  Do I need the response line? What should be the return  httpclient or context? how will it fit into  bean "httpComponentsMessageSender"

Comment: 4.6. Preemptive authentication  --- HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("/");
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(
            targetHost, httpget, context);
    try {
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

    } finally {
        response.close();
    }
In the above is context important or the httpclient ? . It is calling HttpGet here. what about ws:outbound gateway? Also what is that loop 3?

Comment: See an UPDATE in my answer.

Comment: Brilliant. That works. Had to override createConnection and  had to extend HttpComponentsConnection also -----public class CustomHttpComponentsConnection extends HttpComponentsConnection {

 protected CustomHttpComponentsConnection(HttpClient httpClient, HttpPost httpPost, HttpContext httpContext) {
  super(httpClient, httpPost, httpContext);
  
 }

}